# The 'Visual Studio Build Manager Package' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio

Im using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. My laptop suddenly has a problem and I need to do a hard restart.

So after restarting my PC, the problems come out. Every time I open Visual Studio, this message appears:

[image]

The solution explorer is also blank, no files are shown there.

[image]

When I click properties, it shows an error:

[image]

When I try to create a new project, no template is found:

[image]

Here is the latest log:

```
  <entry>
<record>1811</record>
<time>2018/04/25 11:24:45.723</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Build Manager Package]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: The process cannot access the file &apos;C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\dfe52bjz.eei&apos; because it is being used by another process.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file &apos;C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\dfe52bjz.eei&apos; because it is being used by another process.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.&lt;SerializeAssemblyCatalogsAsync&gt;d__48.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.VsExportProviderFactoryWorker.&lt;GetCurrentAssemblyCatalogsAsync&gt;d__15.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.VsExportProviderFactoryWorker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass13_0.&lt;&lt;GetCurrentAssemblyCatalogsAsync&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.VsExportProviderFactory.&lt;GetExportProviderFactoryAsync&gt;d__36.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.&lt;GetMEFV3ExportProviderInternalAsync&gt;d__50.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.&lt;GetMEFV3ExportProviderWrapperAsync&gt;d__49.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass13_1.&lt;&lt;GetValueAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T](Func`1 asyncMethod, JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T](Func`1 asyncMethod)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetLazyValue[T](AsyncLazy`1 lazy)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetExtensions[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.BuildManager.BuildManagerAccessor.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__44.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.BuildManager.BuildManagerPackage.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;&lt;-cctor&gt;b__11_0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ServiceInfo.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15_0.&lt;&lt;ProfferService&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass22_0.&lt;&lt;AddService&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass13_1.&lt;&lt;GetValueAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.BuildManager.BuildManagerPackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__8.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()</description>
<guid>{B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}</guid>
<hr>80070020</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

What I have done:

- Repair Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer - did not solve the problem
- Remove folder `ComponentModelCache` which is located at `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_616f23f4` - did not solve the problem

How can I fix this without reformatting my computer?

Answer (score 0):

After installing on a new path the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I managed to solve it, modifying the policies so that it allowed me to execute script in the power shell. As he did not have permission, he could not automatically download the packages.